# Store MySQL row values as Array values

Tags: mysql, arrays

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT token FROM active_users");

$tokens = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $tokens[] = $row;
}
```

... works, but:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [token] => 32166565
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [token] => 56566565
        )

)
```

whereas I need it to be simply:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 32166565
    [1] => 56566565
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$token[] = $row['token'];
```